# How to web scrape an Interective web page with Rselenium

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

I want to web scrape all properties from this [web page](https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/de/bayern/muenchen/haus-kaufen?pagenumber=3).

When I tried the following code, I only get the details of 1 property on the page.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(RSelenium)
library(stringr)

rD <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome",port = 4234L,chromever = "99.0.4844.51")
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
# test Willhaben
goTo <- remDr$navigate("https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/de/bayern/muenchen/haus-kaufen?pagenumber=3")

Lego <- read_html(remDr$getPageSource(goTo)[[1]])   

rooms <- Lego %>% html_element(".iLQwFF+ .iLQwFF .jXuiQ") %>%
  html_text()

address <- Lego %>% html_element("#skip-to-resultlist .hdZkVR") %>%
  html_text()

cost <- Lego %>% html_element(".result-list-entry__primary-criterion:nth-child(1) .font-highlight") %>%
  html_text()

surface <- Lego %>% html_element(".result-list-entry__primary-criterion:nth-child(2) .font-highlight") %>%
  html_text()

href <- Lego %>% html_element("a.result-list-entry__brand-title-container ") %>%
  html_attr('href')
apt_link <- paste0("https://www.immobilienscout24.de",href)


Munich_flat <- data.frame(apt_link, rooms, surface, cost, address)
```

The result looks like this.
[image]

How can I web scrape all properties on this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you need is to change `html_element` to `html_elements` as the former gets only one node whereas latter gets you all the nodes.

```
Lego <- read_html(remDr$getPageSource(goTo)[[1]])   

rooms <- Lego %>% html_elements('div > div.grid-item.result-list-entry__data-container > div > div.result-list-entry__criteria > a > div > dl:nth-child(3) > dd ') %>%
  html_text()

address <- Lego %>%  html_elements('.result-list-entry__address') %>% 
  html_text()

cost <- Lego %>% html_elements(".result-list-entry__primary-criterion:nth-child(1) .font-highlight") %>%
  html_text()

surface <- Lego %>% html_elements(".result-list-entry__primary-criterion:nth-child(2) .font-highlight") %>%
  html_text()

href <- Lego %>% html_elements("a.result-list-entry__brand-title-container ") %>%
  html_attr('href')

Munich_flat <- data.frame(apt_link, rooms, surface, cost, address)
head(Munich_flat)
                                           apt_link    rooms   surface         cost                                   address
1 https://www.immobilienscout24.de/expose/132791623 37 Zi.37  1.023 m² 10.600.000 € Schlotthauerstraße xx, Untere Au, München
2 https://www.immobilienscout24.de/expose/132872500   5 Zi.5 119,31 m²  1.590.000 €                        Neupasing, München
3 https://www.immobilienscout24.de/expose/132882219   4 Zi.4    148 m²  1.150.000 €                    Waldtrudering, München
4 https://www.immobilienscout24.de/expose/132647642   5 Zi.5    148 m²  1.290.000 €                   Lerchenau-West, München
5 https://www.immobilienscout24.de/expose/132538727 10 Zi.10    840 m²  8.780.000 €      Am alten südlichen Friedhof, München
```